# Menubar is not working after changing logo position

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am using a free wordpress theme [Pitch](http://siteorigin.com/theme/pitch/) . I re positioned the logo and put it in line with menubar .

like this:

[image]

But after doing this not only the drop down but the  whole menu bar doesn't work at all .

How can I make the menubar working at same time maintaining  my desired layout?

Comment: This is my CSS:   http://pastebin.com/SeaaGeYA

Comment: You're joking now right? You pasted 1870 lines of CSS??? Please try to post only related html and CSS

Comment: btw without seeing the actual problem, I assume that you just made a typo at the html/css or you placed your logo inside the `ul` that holds the menu.

Comment: The logo is not a list item . It is separated form menu bar but I re positioned it so , it looks like in same line . 
Here is my css for logo and menu bar

Comment: If you don't post any relevant CSS/HTML I doubt if you'll get an answer

Comment: I only made change to #logo item and in #ul item . 
here is the code 
http://pastebin.com/JxUU9Xq9

Comment: can you just post a link of the actual website? This piece of CSS is not really helping...

Comment: http://aniyanetworks.net/Blog/
@otinanai here is the link

Answer (score 0):

Im not even going to check the css... Because you are using a WordPress theme, there is a good chance you managed to delete a portion of the code that was relating to the menu, because the code was minimized.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the following changes to your CSS and index template file:

For your CSS, edit the following `id`s as following:

```
#mainmenu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 660px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: relative;
}

ul#mainmenu-menu {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F7F7F7 0%, #F4F4F4 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    float: none;
    margin-right: 160px;
    position: relative;
    width: 760px;
}


#logo {
    background: url("images/logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 3px 0 0 -200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
```

For your HTML make the following changes:

1. Remove logo container from where you placed it and put it in the `mainmenu` container like below:

   `<div id="mainmenu" class="">
       <div id="logo">
       <a href="http://aniyanetworks.net/Blog" title="Aniya Network Solutions LTD. - Our Experience is your Business Solutions" id="logo-link"><h1>Aniya Network Solutions LTD.</h1></a>
       </div>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
           <ul id="mainmenu-menu" class="menu">......the rest of the menu HTML here`
2. Don't forget to remove `<div class="container">` inside your logo
   container. It's not needed.
3. If you're OK with my suggestion, tick it as "answered" please.